# CSS Grid Layout - Make an item span as many column as needed

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

I want to use a CSS-Grid-Layout (ideally with an explicit column-grid).
And I would like to have a flexible item that absorbs any extra space along the x axis / spans as many columns as are not used by other items.

The perfect solution would be a property that makes an item span across all unoccupied columns (similar to the flex-property) - but I guess that's not possible in a CSS-Grid.

I'll try to make an example:

The following Layout uses several elements that are positioned  on a grid.
I would like to have a flexible header, that absorbs any extra space on the right if the item in the area "aside1" is cut.

```
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  none  1fr    1fr    none;
  grid-template-areas:  "header header header aside1"
                      "nav    main   main   aside2"
                      "nav    main   main   aside3"
                      ;
} 

header {
grid-area: header;
}

main {
 grid-area: main;
}

nav {
 grid-area: nav;
}

.aside1 {
 grid-area: aside1;
}

.aside2 {
 grid-area: aside2;
}

.aside3 {
 grid-area: aside3;
}
```

[image]

But, of course, as long as there are any items on the right side, the header will stay in it's column an the Layout will look like this:

[image]

In a Flexbox-Layout I could use the flex: 1 property to accomplish this.

In Grid... I guess I would need a way to have a box Item to absorb all unused columns. Maybe that is not possible to do.

```
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  none  1fr   none;
} 

header {
  grid-column: 1 / ????; 
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

main {
  grid-column: 2 / 3; 
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

nav {
  grid-column: 2 / 3; 
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.aside1 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 /  2;
}

.aside2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 /  3;
}

.aside3 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 /  4;
}
```

What I am trying to do ist to build a small "framwork" with a flexible xy-Grid, similar to foundation, but um.. not that cool (it's a school project).

And I was wondering if it's possible to build a grid system with both:

1. Grid Items, that absorb any free space/columns along the x-axis - possible with flex-Grid and in foundation.
2. Grid items, that span several rows - not possible with flex-Grid, see: [Is it possible for flex items to align tightly to the items above them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480760/is-it-possible-for-flex-items-to-align-tightly-to-the-items-above-them) (the first answer explains it pretty well)

I hope I made myself a little bit more clear.

Comment: I was hoping for a similar behavior as when you have a row with flex items and one of them has a value of  flex:1 and the other items have fixed width. The flex:1 item takes up all the free space between the fixed items.
So it should only span across the entire row, when there is no other item on it.   
The main Idea would be to have a flexible grid, in which an item on the side can be cut out an the main-section fills up alle the available space. 
And to build it with the CSS-Grid-Layout. Just interested if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use `grid-template-columns` for your explicitly sized columns and `grid-auto-columns` for any additional flexible columns.

While [**`grid-template-columns`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing) sizes columns in the *explicit* grid, [**`grid-auto-columns`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks) sizes columns in the *implicit* grid.

So try sizing your columns like this:

```
grid-template-columns: 100px 100px  /* sizes the first two columns */
grid-auto-columns:  1fr             /* distributes free space among additional columns; if
                                       there is only one column, it consumes all space; */
```

This post may also be useful:

- [CSS Grid: How to make a column span full width when a second column is not there?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43301949/3597276)

Comment: I have thinking about this question for quite a time, but I can't seem to find a solution. Sometimes it looks like it's doable, but at the end, there is always some kind of issue   ...

Comment: I think there is a general impression that with CSS Grid *all* layout problems have been solved. The truth is that *many* layout problems have been solved, but definitely not all. CSS v1 (1996) left a lot to be desired. The same could be said about CSS Grid Level 1 (2017). Give it some time :-) @vals

Comment: Thank you. The Answers on the link are pretty close to what I was trying to do. Not 100%. But as you said, most likely it's just not possible to do (yet).