# Using minmax() functions in CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid, minmax

I have a grid with 2 columns x 2 rows. All of them are set in `minmax()` size. Can I ask why the element with class `show` doesn't take the full size of the grid even though I set all other elements (`hide` class) in the grid to width 0 and height 0. Doesn't `minmax()` work properly?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 :root {
  --seemoresz: 100px;
}

#outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(calc(700px - var(--seemoresz)), 700px) minmax(0px, var(--seemoresz));
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0px, var(--seemoresz)) minmax(calc(700px - var(--seemoresz)), 700px);
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.hide {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="hide">
    hide this
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    hide this
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    show this
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    hide this
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `minmax()` function is working fine. So is the `calc()` function.

The problem is a misunderstanding about the minimum height and widths that are set.

Even though you set the grid items to zero width and height:

```
.hide {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

...the grid columns have their own width and height:

```
#outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(calc(700px - var(--seemoresz)), 700px) minmax(0px, var(--seemoresz));
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0px, var(--seemoresz)) minmax(calc(700px - var(--seemoresz)), 700px);
}
```

The columns and rows aren't shrinking to zero, which prevents `.show` from expanding across the entire container.

Consider using `auto` instead of `minmax()` in `grid-template-*`. That will enable the column / row to track the size of the grid item.

Also consider the solutions in these posts:

- [How to make a column span full width when a second column is not there? (CSS Grid)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43301949/3597276)
- [Is it possible to hide columns with empty content via the grid-template-columns definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56433889/3597276)
- [minmax() defaulting to max](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50654400/3597276)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer. I have tried your solution and it works like a charm. However, I still don't understand why minmax() function works like that because I thought minmax() supposed to range the size of the column/row from min to max based on the its grid child ? Did I miss something right here. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi. You're welcome. With regard to `minmax()`, did you have a chance to review the link I provided (last bullet point)?